# SDHC unreadable on Windows 8, on OSX works fine

Tags: windows, sdhc

Whenever I try to read a 8GB SDHC on Windows 8 (using two different card readers), it says that the card needs to be formatted, but from the camera (CanonSX240HS) the photos are readable.

Looking at the properties, it says that it is in "DCF file system". Wasn't supposed to be FAT32 ?

I have tha same issues with two cards, both 8GB, different manufactor.

Then I tried to read the card on a MacMini, using the internal card reader, and it works fine!

I'm quite confused, so some questions that come in mind:

- Are there issues with Windows 8 and DCF?
- Should I format to FAT32?
- I tried to connect the camera via USB, the files are there, but it takes about 45 minutes to download 6GB of photos. Isn't it too much?

Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Windows 8 tech support. 

Comment: Not answering as I am not sure, but I would try and format the card on your windows system with fat32 and then see how it goes. Well actually I just use a Mac :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come across that.

It's because the card reader you're using doesn't support SDHC and nothing to do with Windows 8 at all.  Don't format the card on the PC as you'll create a 2gb partition and then that's all your camera will format.

Get yourself a decent reader and the problem will disappear.

Comment: The silly think is that the reader is quite new (and states it can read SDHC), while a five years old Eee PC (running Linux) can read is without issues...  You are right about formatting too, I already ruined a pendrive in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Design rule for Camera File system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_rule_for_Camera_File_system), DCF is a meta specification for camera memory cards that is based on FAT style formatting.

So if you are having issues on a W8 system and not the OSX system and not when using USB, then as per mattdm it is a W8 issue.

You are better off asking this question on http://superuser.com

And as per formatting, I generally only format a card in the camera itself.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you copy off all the images from the card and reformat it.

I've had issues in the past on Windows computer where a card was formatted FAT32 but the cluster size was set to something small like 8K and Windows refused to recognize it.  Once it was reformatted to FAT32 with a 32K cluster size, it worked in Windows.